# What's the best way to get rid of notices about undefined variables?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use codeigniter, one of the main issues i have with the views is undefined variables that may or may not exist.

I know that it's easy to get rid of the notices when using something like:

```
<?=html($this->input->post('name'))?>
```

By adding `if(isset(..){ html($this->input->post('name')); }`

But it's very annoying and it  makes the code look ugly, I also don't want to disable notice reporting.

Is there any advice about that?

Comment: Write code that doesn't leave variables undefined?

Comment: @delnan: his full question makes a bit more sense than just the title taken out of context. He's taking user input, so it's very possible that something would be left undefined, and he needs to handle that case. Even so, I'd still agree that it's better to, ya know, actually handle the case than sweep it under the rug.

Comment: @delnan you don't make any actual sense

Comment: I would monkey patch the CI ->post input variable fetching method to omit the redundant notices. (As you know, they are both to be expected and therefore redundant.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "best" way? I still say it's `isset`. It's nice to be explicit, and it would help me, as someone maintaining your code later, to realize that you are okay with that variable not existing and that it wasn't just a mistake. Unless the `isset` check were there, I'd assume you just didn't realize it was possible for it not to be set, and would wonder what you actually meant to do.

Additionally, I'd assert that one of the main reasons it looks ugly is because all the code is being crammed into one line. There are two things you're trying to do: check if it's set, and print it if so. Maybe spacing them out would look nicer, even if it's a bit more verbose:

```
<?php if( isset($this->input->post('name')) ): ?>
    <?= $this->input->post('name') ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

This also makes the snippet easier to manage later, in case you later decide to, say, wrap the output in an HTML tag, or add an `else` case.

Plus, since, according to the question, we can't mess with the error reporting settings, checking for the variable's existence is the *only* option. Sorry. Either you check if it's set, or disable the error messages saying it's not. No middle road.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll find the *error reporting()* php  function located at the top of your main index.php file.
Then have a look to the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) that says for your question :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to define your variables always. If the variable is an input (i.e. You don't know whether it is defined or not) then using isset() required. Personally I use a wrapper function to get data from input variables:

```
function get($key, $default = null) {
    return isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : $default);
}
```

Then instead of using `$_GET['some_key']` you can use `get('some_key')`.

You can also suppress errors using at sign (@) which I do not recommend.

Comment: Why do you not recommend using "@"?

Comment: Because it's hard to trace code in case of any problem. See the warning on http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your controller in function __construct() part.

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE));
}
```